# C++11 - User defined string operator overload from char[]

Tags: c++, c++11, user-defined-literals

Read about the user defined literals, and find it somehow obscure about defining a string literal overload from `char[]`.

The definitely correct way is like this

```
std::string operator "" _s (const char* m, std::size_t)
{
    return std::string(m);
}

int main()
{
    std::string r = "hello,"_s + " world"_s;
    return 0;
}
```

But in fact the type of something like `"hello"` is `const char (&)[N]` (where `N` is the length). So I wonder if there is an alternative approach like this

```
template <std::size_t N>
std::string operator "" _s (const char (&m)[N])
{
    return std::string(m);
}
```

But oops the compiler (g++4.8 in Ubuntu 14.04) gave me an error

```
‘std::string operator"" _s(const char (&)[N])’ has invalid argument list
 std::string operator "" _s (char const (&m)[N])
                                               ^
```

Then I tried to remove the unused `std::size_t` parameter from the correct way (`std::string operator "" _s (const char* m)`) but got the error

```
unable to find string literal operator ‘operator"" _s’ with ‘const char [7]’, ‘long unsigned int’ arguments
     std::string r = "hello,"_s + " world"_s;
```

So is that mandatory to have the length as a parameter when the primary literal is a `char[]` or a `wchar_t[]`?

Comment: perhaps http://eel.is/c++draft/over.literal#3 applies

Comment: Documentation: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/user_literal#Literal_operators

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Thanks. `float operator ""_e(const char*); // OK` Does it mean if the literal is `1111_e` it will match the overload without the length parameter?

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot That's not "documentation" that's a public wiki.

Comment: @neuront String literals decay anyway, and there is no array constructor for `std::string`. So I'm unsure to what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @neuront Yes, it would if there are no `operator ""_e(unsigned long long )` defined.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper it is a wiki aiming to document C++ language in readable and accessible form. Like expected _"Stackoverflow Documentation"_

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot I know what the site is. I don't agree with people calling it documentation when it's a third party website that can be edited by anybody. Incorrect information has been posted there in the past.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper It is documentation inasmuch it documents something. Any documentation, whether equipped with some kind of official blessing or not, may contain errors (yes this includes standards of all kinds).

Comment: @n.m. The w3school has in much in common with the W3C as cppreference does with ISO C++. But so much as it's "documentation" it's just as good as the official thing, right?

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper It could be as good as the official documentation. It could also be better or worse. Depends on how useful it is for a particular audience. cppreference.com is IMHO more useful than the actual standard for a common programmer, because a common programmer can derive answers he needs faster *and more accurately* on average from cppreference than from the standard. A compiler writer will probably find the standard more useful.

Comment: @n.m. You are missing the point. The point is people are carelessly referring to "cppreference" as **the** documentation as if it's authoritative. It's not. It's a public wiki that can be modified by **anybody** at **any time**. I'm not saying it's a bad site, I'm saying it's an issue of branding. Would you hire somebody who got a certificate from W3School because it's "good enough"? I hope not.

Comment: @uhohsomebodyneedsapupper I have no idea how good is W3School so let me refrain from discussing it. I do know that cppreference is very good indeed. I don't think many people mistake it for the authoritative reference.